# Instance of T (generic type) in Java

Tags: java, generics

In short: Why cannot I write the following code in Java?

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public void foo(Object bar) {
        if (bar instanceof T) {
            // todo
        }
    }
}
```

Yeah, I know, the generics is kinda hacked into Java. Generics wasn't there until Java 1.5, and the generic type is lost during runtime.

I also know, there are some patterns for it. For example:

```
public class Foo<T> {

    Class<T> clazz;

    public Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void foo(Object bar) {
        if (clazz.isInstance(bar)) {
            // todo
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, why isn't it automatically done by the compiler?

For each class, where any generic type is present, the compiler could automatically add one (or more, if I have more generic types) parameter for each constructor, and bind those values to private fields. And each time, I write `bar instanceof T` it could compile this as `clazzOfGenericT.isInstance(bar)`.

Is there any reason, this is not implemented?

I'm not totally sure, this wouldn't break backwards compatibility* - but then, new JVM languages (like Scala, or Kotlin) why doesn't have this feature?

*: IMHO it could be done, without break any backwards compatibility.

Comment: It'd break all the code that implicitly depends on `T` not being a real thing, and that you can hackily cast around it.

Comment: There are complications if the types are themseleves generic. e.g. List<List<String>>.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: yeah... I don't know the exact language specs about the generics, but was it ever documented, or specified? If not, then it could be done, in my opinion.

Comment: All the details of erasure were absolutely specified.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: didn't think of that, thanks! (but also, I cannot write `list instanceof List<String>`, just `list instanceof List` - and that could be done this way.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman: could you tell me an example where this 'hackily cast' thing is usefull and necessary? And, if this is necessary, new JVM languages why didn't implement this somehow? There won't be a problem the backward compatibility.

Comment: The whole idea of generics was based on the assumption that you'd prefer to write `public void foo(T bar)` instead of taking an `Object` parameter and checking it with `instanceof` at runtime. You don't really need generics if you want to do the latter. (Of course the two aren't technically incompatible, but conceptually they are two different world views and more often than not, nothing good comes out of trying to mix them.)

Comment: By the way, how would you handle bounded/unbounded wildcards? And self-bound types? There are some very tricky edge cases that you don't really have to think about when you're writing your manual workaround, but they need to be dealt with as soon as this becomes part of the language. Again, it doesn't sound impossible, but the JLS is pretty byzantine as it is.

Comment: @biziclop: in case of wildcards, you couldn't write `instanceof ?`, only `instanceof T` (where the generics was `? extends T`). I think, this could be handled with the class-as-parameter method also.

Comment: @NagyVilmos But what if I had a variable of type `Foo<?>`? And what would happen with `? super X`?

Comment: @biziclop: i don't want to allow `instanceof ?`, so your first example is irrelevant, I think. In the second, you could write `instanceof X`, but you couldn't `instanceof ?`. And `X` would be known at compile time, so no problem, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proposals for features added to Java are slow-moving and there are higher-priority features. "They haven't gotten to it yet."

> Generics wasn't there until Java 1.5, and the generic type is lost during runtime.
>
> ...
>
> My question is, why isn't it automatically done by the compiler?
>
> For each class, where any generic type is present, the compiler could automatically add one (or more, if I have more generic types) parameter for each constructor, and bind those values to private fields.

Well, now, here you're just asking why Java doesn't store generic type information for run-time. You're asking for reification. The answer is that Java's generics are implemented with erasure, which you already know.

Yes, reification is possible and other languages do it. Yes, maybe Java will do it someday too. Maybe they will do it in a way similar to what you've suggested. Or maybe not.

Something like this could eventually be addressed by [Project Valhalla](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/).